# Get last value from child in xml

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am trying to get the value of the id last booking in an xml-file.

This is my code:

```
        XElement id = (from p in z.Elements("booking")
                           select p.Element("id")).Last();
```

However this returns the tags aswell: 5
Any idea how to get the value without the -tags?

the xml-file looks soemthing like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bookings>
<booking>
<id>1</id>
<name>a</name>
</booking>
<booking>
<id>2</id>
<name>b</name>
</booking>
</bookings>
```

Comment: can you show the xml file ? how is the `id` element look like? by _tags_ did you mean element names ?

Comment: @Tess Give me please few minutes to check it out. Thanks.

Comment: @Selman22 yes I mean the element names

Comment: @Tess Since I tested it locally and it worked for me, I assume that there should be a subtle point that we have to fix in order you get what you want. One question, the z in your code represents your xml file?

Comment: @Christos I spoke too soon, I realized just now that I used "XElement z = XElement.Load(path2);" instead of XDocument. It works fine now! Thank you so much for all your help and patience :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
XElement lastElement = (from p in doc.Elements("bookings").Elements("booking")
                        select p.Element("id")).LastOrDefault();

if(lastElement!=null)
    var value = lastElement.Value;
```

I suppose that `doc` is the object that represents you xml.

Before the code I wrote above, you should have declared this

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
```

I supposed that the name of the xml file is test.xml.

Comment: You cannot convert an `XElement` to an `string`. You should read the `Value` property of `XElement`.

Comment: @MD.Unicorn yes you can.there are some conversions defined from XElement to string and other types such as int, double, DateTime.See the documentation for more details

Comment: Thanks for replying. Using your code I still get the tags <id>555</id> and I  want the value without the tags.

Comment: @MD.Unicorn yes you can, please look here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387049.aspx

Comment: @Tess I will update my post in few minutes. Thanks for being patient.

Comment: If you cast to string, you avoid NullReferenceException at runtime

Comment: @Tess how is your id element look like ?

Comment: @Selman22 I thougt without using the Value property would work. But now I updated my post, in which I use the property called Value. I hope this will work

Comment: @Christos the explicit cast should work, you really don't need to use Value property.If you want to then cast is redundant because it returns a string, I think the problem is in somewhere else.the only thing I can imagine is something like: `<id><id>12</id></id>`

Comment: @Selman22 ok I got it. Thanks for mentioning this. I hope Tess shed more light in order to find where the problem is.

Comment: @Selman22 & Christos: Oh! I didn't know that (obviously)! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If there will always be at least one booking, then you should get a value for the id.  If there can be no id's in the file (hence no bookings) then id will be `""` or `string.Empty` depending how you like referring to an empty string.

```
string id = (string)z.Descendants("id").LastOrDefault();
```

Comment: Thank you Chuck. The problem was solved a couple of days ago by Christos, but I appreciate you taking the time to help me.

Comment: @Tess Sure - Mark his answer as the correct one, so others don't think there hasn't been a satisfactory answer.